# SSPI always picks up NTLM

Tags: windows, active-directory, kerberos, ntlm, sspi

I have a windows7 connected to a windows2008-r2 domain.

Each time I try a SSPI "Negociate" (C++), I fall back to NTLM.

I do not understand why...
DNS on DC are ok.

Something to do I don't ??

If I run a klist I can see all the right, everything seems to be ok (I guess)

**Update**

Ok now I'm just beginning to understand (at least).

I used to give the SPN "" to `InitializeSecurityContext` which, in that case falls back directly to NTLM.

Now i tried, always on my client, this:

```
    wchar_t szSPN[256]={0};
    ULONG cchSPN = sizeof szSPN / sizeof *szSPN;
    GetUserNameEx(NameDnsDomain, szSPN, &cchSPN);
    ...
    InitializeSecurityContext( hCred, NULL, szPSN, ...)
```

which gives me back error 0x8009030c

**Other weird stuff :**
If I set szSPN with "Administrator", now it works with kerberos !!!
But
If I set szSPN with JOE, it fails... (Assuming I created on DC, a new user JOE).

Wawww, I don't understand what's going on... !?

Comment: Have you tried to pick Kerberos package and check for `SECURITY_STATUS`?

Answer (score 0):

What is the resource you are trying to access?  It must be a server/service that is properly configured for Kerberos.